# Best way to post NSNotification with NSRect info?

Tags: cocoa, notifications, nsnotifications

what is the best way to post a notification with NSRect info?

Here is my current solution (using NSStringFromRect).

```
- (void)postNotificationForDirtyRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = 
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: NSStringFromRect(rect) 
                                     forKey: ILDirtyRect];

    NSNotificationCenter *ncenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [ncenter postNotificationName: ILDocumentBecomeDirtyRectNotification
                           object: self 
                         userInfo: userInfo];
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to send a rect struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using an [NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) created using the `+valueWithRect:` class method.